# Is PyBuffer_Release required after Py_BuildValue("y#", ...)?

Tags: python, python-c-api, pybuffer

If it makes a difference, I am interested in an answer regarding Python 3.

The docs state ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html)) that `PyBuffer_Release()` should be called after `PyArg_Parse*()` with `s*`, `y*`.

Nothing of the sort is written about `Py_BuildValue()`. Is it an oversight, or in case of `Py_BuildValue()` a `simple Py_DECREF()` is enough?

Here is my specific case:

```
uint8_t buf = (uint8_t *)malloc(bufSize);
PyObject *pyBuf = Py_BuildValue("y#", (char *)buf, bufSize);
free(buf);

// do something with pyBuf

// maybe a PyBuffer_Release(get_underlying_buffer(pyBuf)) here?
Py_DECREF(pyBuf);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no:

1. In both the `PyArg_Parse*` and `Py_BuildValue` functions, `y#` refers to a string and length, rather than a buffer, and therefore there is no underlying buffer object to be released.
2. The documentation for `Py_BuildValue` says:

   > When memory buffers are passed as parameters to supply data to build objects, as for the s and s# formats, the required data is copied. Buffers provided by the caller are never referenced by the objects created by Py_BuildValue().

   The purpose of holding a lock on the buffer used by `PyArg_Parse*` is that you have got *a reference* to some data *out* of Python to C, and you want to process it in C without any chance of it being modified by Python. In this case you have *copied* some data from C into Python and so there's no need to protect the original data from modification.

Comment: **"In this case you have copied some data from C into Python and so there's no need to protect the original data from modification."** - I think at this point Python might decide that there is a new object that has a reference to that copied buffer, therefore during the construction of `Py_buffer` some internal reference counter is increased that later must be released by `PyBuffer_Release()`. At least, this is what I fear. Maybe the newly created object is itself a `Py_buffer`. Maybe later I will create some testcode to ascertain what objects are created and what resources they hold.

Comment: When I test this the newly created object is a `bytes` object (the only other realistic option was a `bytearray`). This does expose the buffer interface, and so It would be possible to get a `Py_buffer`. However, even if `Py_BuildValue` produced one requiring the buffer to be released, you could do nothing about it since you don't have access to whatever `Py_buffer` it had created

Comment: So basically, whatever resources are automatically held within `bytes`, those should be released by the `bytes` object automatically. That makes sense. I think for absolute certainty, the python code would have to be looked up. For now it is good enough for me.